# Chemical bonding with f orbitals

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

For the elements such as rhenium, osmium, iridium how probable is for electrons in the inner 4f orbitals to gain energy and take part in a molecular orbital (such as an $f^2 d^2 s p^3$ hybrid orbital) when these elements are in their 6,7,8,9 oxidation state?

Comment: There's no such hybrid and d block doesn't use f-electrons for bonding.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintuple_bond

Comment: You should read papers: [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01143a056), [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1742807) and [here](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2016/dt/c6dt00634e)